# table length attribute converted to string returns nothing

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I've been trying to figure out this bug for a little while now and I cannot find anything about it online.

**What I expect to happen:**

When the create row button is pressed is that a new row is created at the bottom of the table. The row has three cells. The first is the index, the second is " New 1 " and the third is " New 2 ".

**What is happening:**

That I do not want to happen is that the first cell in new rows appears empty. Inspecting it shows that it actually has no content. Saving the string to a variable then adding it to the inner html of a cell does not work either. However if I log that variable to the console it does print the correct index.

```js
function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var test = table.rows.length.toString()
  cell2.innerHTML = test.toString()
  console.log(test)
  cell2.innerHTML = " NEW 1 ";
  cell3.innerHTML = " NEW 2 ";
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length - 1);
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<p/>

<form>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

</form>
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that I'm just not seeing. If anyone could help shed light on my issue that would be wonderful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never set the content of `cell1`.

Comment: sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes, thanks @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell1.innerHTML = test;     
cell2.innerHTML = " NEW 1 ";
cell3.innerHTML = " NEW 2 ";
```

As simply as that

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting any value to `cell1`.

In fact your problem is that you are inserting the index in the `cell2`  instead of `cell1`, so `cell1` is always empty.

Just change this line:

```
cell2.innerHTML = test.toString();
```

To:

```
cell1.innerHTML = test;
```

**Demo:**

```js
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var test = table.rows.length.toString()
    cell1.innerHTML = test;
    console.log(test)
    cell2.innerHTML = " NEW 1 ";
    cell3.innerHTML = " NEW 2 ";
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length-1);
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<p/>

<form>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `innerHTML` of the first inserted cell. You must have forgotten to set the `innerHTML` of the first cell and instead set the `innerHTML` of the second cell twice.

Change

```
cell2.innerHTML = test.toString()
```

To

```
cell1.innerHTML = test;//you do not need to invoke toString() on a String
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<p/>

<form>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 1 </td>
      <td> NEW 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

</form>

<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var test = table.rows.length.toString()
    cell1.innerHTML = test;
    console.log(test)
    cell2.innerHTML = " NEW 1 ";
    cell3.innerHTML = " NEW 2 ";
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length-1);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```